# How to parse elements from Sparql algebra

Tags: sparql, jena

I can get the algebra form from sparql query string using ARQ algebra (*com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.algebra*):

```
String queryStr = 
   "PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>" + 
              "SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?nick" +
              "{?x foaf:mbox <mailt:person@server> ." + 
              "?x foaf:name ?name" +
              "OPTIONAL { ?x foaf:nick ?nick }}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr);
Op op = Algebra.compile(query);
```

Print the returned value of op:

```
(distinct
(project (?name ?nick)
(join
  (bgp
    (triple ?x <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/mbox> <mailt:person@server>)
    (triple ?x <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> ?nameOPTIONAL)
  )
  (bgp (triple ?x <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/nick> ?nick)))))
```

Returned value is an Op type, but I can't find any direct methods that can parse the **op** into elements, e.g., basic graph patterns of s, p, o, and the relations between these graph patterns.

Any hint is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether that printed output conforms to a nice grammar or not.  It might, but in general, the result of `toString` (which is what you're seeing here) is about providing a _human_ readable description of an object, and not necessarily an unambiguous machine readable representation.  It's often possible to figure out ways to "break" attempts to parse toString output.  E.g., see [Parsing List<Map<String,String>> String form to POJO again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21709875/1281433).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why serialise out the algebra at all?

If your aim is to walk the algebra tree and extract the BGPs then you can do this using the [`OpVisitor`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/algebra/OpVisitor.html) interface of which there are various implementations of that will get you started.  The particular method you would care about is `visit(OpBgp opBgp)` since then you can access the methods of the [`OpBgp`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/algebra/op/OpBGP.html) class to extract the pattern information

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run sparql queries over distributed framework, then I think getting the algebra tree is necessary. Actually I need some time to understand **visit** functions.

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late but still as I am not seeing final answer so I am writing the code for printing all **BGP**.

For that create the class as follows that extends `OpVisitorBase` and override the public void visit(final **OpBGP**) function as given below in the code.

And from your code simply call the function:

`MyOpVisitorBase.myOpVisitorWalker(op);`

```
public class MyOpVisitorBase extends OpVisitorBase
{
    public static void myOpVisitorWalker(Op op)
    {
        OpWalker.walk(op, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(final OpBGP opBGP) {
        final List<Triple> triples = opBGP.getPattern().getList();
        int i = 0;
        for (final Triple triple : triples) {
            System.out.println("Triple: "+triple.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you call "this" in a static context?